# A die roll and Binomial distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

[image]

<sup>[Note: This is not an accurate picture. This picture is given to give a sense only.](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/basic-statistics/probability-distributions/supporting-topics/distributions/binomial-distribution/)</sup>

Suppose, I assign probabilities to a die according to Binomial distribution. I.e. 1 and 6 have least probability of occurring, and 3 and 4 have the highest probability of occurring?

Can we say that the "The die roll experiment has a Binomial distribution"?

Why or why not?

Comment: No, there are only six possible outcomes, the distribution is not "continuous", no chance to use the word *normal* in a good sense, i would complain at any rate.

Comment: @dan_fulea, what about Poisson or any other distribution, but not the uniform one?

Comment: The situation is rather simple, we only need to fix and publish six values, $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_4, p_5,p_6\ge 0$, summing to one, this is a discrete probability space determined by this data. The situation is simple, naming is not so important, but if naming is the issue, then call it finite discrete probability space, and the repartition function has jumps, it is in most cases not useful, there is no density for it, just call it staircase if this is really needed. (And there are not too many steps in it.)